# SharePoint List CSR handler are not fired - SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, client-side-templating

I am trying to change style of sharepoint list using CSR. I want to apply bold to title column. I have added these code in JS file and reffered as JSLink(JavaScriptDisplayTemplate) to webpart. On document ready both renderTitleHandler & preRenderHandler are registered and also preRenderHandler are called successfully. But renderTitleHandler are not fired.

Please find my code snippet,

```
function renderTitleHandler(ctx) {
var fieldVal = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
var title = fieldVal.toString();
var html = '';
html += '<b>' + title + '</b>';
return html;
}

function preRenderHandler(ctx) {
     ctx.ListTitle =  '<b>' + ctx.ListTitle + '</b>';
}

(function() {

var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.OnPreRender = preRenderHandler;

overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "Title" : {"View" : renderTitleHandler}
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

Thanks in advance. 
Kannan.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

- disable Minimal Download Strategy (mds). Sometimes this blocks your
  javascripts caused by the async loading in the back of certain OOTB
  scripts
- remove the debugger;-line (is it possible that your code works when developer tools in your browser are open?)

Edit:
Found an example on my dev environment and i have the word View between quotes:

```
linkFilenameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Title": { "View": renderTitleHandler}
    };
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Minimal download strategy is not active. Also tried removing debugger. Still it is not working.

Comment: Ok, check my addition on the response. Hope it helps you

Comment: I have tried placing Title and View between double and single quotes, but still facing same issue.

Comment: Ok, just one idea then: have you tried to placing overrideCtx.Templates.OnPreRender = preRenderHandler; before overrideCtx.Templates.Fields ? Looks like we're the only one in here :-)

Comment: There is also a little mistake in <b>' + ctx.ListTitle) + '</b> (remove the ')').

Comment: I have changed as per your suggestions and updated the above code sample, but the changes not reflected in List. We able to customize the items using the below codes. Only field customization is not working.

Comment: (function () {
   var itemCtx = {};  itemCtx.Templates = {};      itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);
})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {
  var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Description;
return "<p><b>" + _announcementTitle + "</b></p></p>" + _announcementDesc  + "</p>";
}